# Print only Stylesheet on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I created a print-only template and stylesheet for my Rails 4 app. Everything works great on my local environment, but in production (on Heroku) the view cannot find the stylesheet. I have tried `rake assets:precompile`, and that did not seem to help either. Also - if possible - I would like to exclude this stylesheet from all other views. Any ideas?

**in my purchase request controller**

```
def print
    @purchase_request = PurchaseRequest.find(params[:id])
    render :layout => "print" 
end
```

**/views/purchase_requests/print.html.erb**

```
<p>
  Purchase Request
</p>
<table>
  # I have omitted the table data in the interest of brevity
</table>
```

**/views/layouts/print.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Depot</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "print", media: :all %>
</head
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<%= yield %>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**/assets/stylesheets/print.css.scss (not really necessary, but in the interest of completeness)**

```
table {
    border: 2px solid #000;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;

    td {
        border-top: 2px solid #000;
        padding: .5em;
    }

    td.key, td.signature_key {
        border-right: 2px solid #000;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    td.signature_key, td.signature_blank {
        padding: 2em;
    }
}
p {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you've followed the [Heroku guideline for Rails 4](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails4).

It will precompile assets only if you add `gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production` to your Gemfile.

**UPDATE**

You need to include print.css to your **environments/production.rb** file also:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( print.css)
```

Comment: Yes, that is included. Assets work fine everywhere else - it is only the print layout that is having trouble.

Comment: You need to include print.css to your environments/production.rb file also: config.assets.precompile += %w( print.css)